# ARKit 2: Virtual Objects are floating when the ARWorldMap is reloaded from backend

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am currently working on an app that saves and reloads [AR World Maps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap) (made possible due to the release of ARKit 2 at WWDC18). When I retrieve a world map stored on my backend and run an ar session with the reloaded [configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration), the objects float around until the objects are placed on their original surface (from the original session). I was able to prevent this issue by hiding the objects until I could assert that the object [anchors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor) are [ARPlaneAnchors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplaneanchor), but this does not work any more after apple released the beta 4 update to iOS, which has also updated the ARKit SDK. Has anyone else encountered this issue and/or found a solution to it?

Here is the code that fixed this issue before:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    if let _ = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
        for object in self.virtualObjectLoader.loadedObjects {
            if object.modelName == anchor.name {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    object.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At what point are you adding your objects to the scene ( during relocalization ) ? I think you are being too fast.

Also, I found that adding multiple ARAnchors around my objects helps with some of the "sliding/shifting".

ARWorldMaps have an array of ARAnchors which will be added to your scene during relocalization, I have assigned one of these anchors as my object's anchor and once I see them placed in renderer:didAddNode:ForAnchor: I add my object with that anchor.

```
guard let object = items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                return item.anchor == anchor
            }).first else { return }
// Then add the object
```